# getting the all logged in users using ajax

Tags: visualforce

.rTable { display: table; }

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
</script>
<script src="../../soap/ajax/37.0/connection.js"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     window.onload = setupPage;
function setupPage() {

  var state = { //state that you need when the callback is called
      output : document.getElementById("output"),
      startTime : new Date().getTime()};

  var callback = {
      onSuccess: layoutResults,

      onFailure: queryFailed,
      source: state};

  sforce.connection.query(
      "Select UsersId, UserType,IsCurrent,users.name From AuthSession ",
       callback);
```

}

function queryFailed(error, source) {
    source.output.innerHTML = "An error has occurred: " + error;
  }

function layoutResults(queryResult, source) {
    if (queryResult.size > 0) {
        var records = queryResult.getArray('records');
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            var user = records[i];

```
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + user.UsersId + '</td>' + '<td>' + user.UserType  + '</td>'+ '<td>' + user.IsCurrent + '</td>';
        document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(tr);         
    }
    source.output.innerHTML = output;
}
```

}

```
<html>
```

Id 

         Name 
         iscurrent

i tried to get all the logged in users,,am getting ids ,i also want to display the names.need help to meet this.thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query instead:

```
select name from user where id in 
    (select usersid from authsession where iscurrent = true)
```

This will give you a de-duplicated list of all the users with current sessions by name. You can also select any of the other usual User fields.

Alternatively, UsersId is a normal relationship field, so you can also do:

```
select users.name from authsession where iscurrent = true
```

Comment: Unfortunate choice of `API Name`, that. `UsersId`...

Comment: select users.name from authsession where iscurrent = true   i,used this,,i want to add this to <tr>,,,see my updated code

Comment: @sahisfdc `var user = records[i];` ... `+ user.Users.Name +`; make sure you check the capitalization of the variables.

Comment: when i run this query it only returns the running user (myself) unless I remove IsCurrent. I  have tested multiple times.  Can you confirm that it returns all logged in users for you?  I have an open question for this [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309060/querying-authsession-with-iscurrent-true-only-shows-my-user)