# Querying AuthSession with IsCurrent = TRUE only shows my user

Tags: authentication, login, session

While we may not be leading the pack in Salesforce adoption, I'm quite sure that a number of our 400 users are still logged in as If I look at session management in setup, there are plenty of UI sessions that are still valid.

But if I query `select users.name from authsession where iscurrent = true` as suggested by [this sfse response by sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/129705/10062) it only returns my user.  The response clearly states that this should return all users.

> This will give you a de-duplicated list of all the users with current sessions by name. You can also select any of the other usual User fields.

I have tried in dev console and via anonymous apex.  I am a system administrator.  Does this look like a bug, or is there something I am missing here?  FWIW my org is quite old.

Screenshots below

Dev Console Query Output
[image: dev console query output]

UI Sessions in Session Management (filtered for parentId = blank)
[image: session management active user]

Answer (score 0):

Filtering on the `isCurrent` field on [AuthSession](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_authsession.htm) for true values returns only values that correspond to your current session (hence, why it only returns your session records).

> If true, the session is a member of the **user’s current session family**.
>   This field is available in API version 37.0 and later.

If you remove that filter, you'll see others' AuthSession's records as you see in the UI.

Comment: agree that is what we are seeing. i read the phrase "users current session family" to mean the current session family for all users in the query, instead of "current users session family" which is what we are seeing.  the link i provided to a response by sfdcfox indicated this should be for all users.  so either that post is incorrect, or there is something else going on.